# Vagrant file: how to execute shell on a specific box

Tags: vagrant

When I do `vagrant up --provision` using the attached vagrant file, the specified shell command gets executed on both vms (puppet and node1). How can I execute shell command on a single vm (puppet only) where more than one vms are specified.

[Vagrant file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C5iF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
config.vm.provision "shell" ....
```

to

```
puppet.vm.provision "shell" ....
```

this will make sure it gets executed on the `puppet` machine

note: for reference in your future question, its better to copy/paste your code inside your question than attaching a screenshot of your IDE (which is not really practical)